# How to validate an interval entered to a text input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there a way to define a number interval (let's say between 1900 and 2016) in jQuery that can **only** be entered to a text input field?

As far as I understand, I have to use input type="text" because the number field can't be used for a jQuery keyboard. In addition, it is required that values be entered both by a virtual and real keyboard (see http://generace.forbes.cz/) and that the number interval be checked each time user tries to submit the form.

Comment: Where there's a will, there's a way.  Where's your attempt?

Comment: You can use the pattern attribute to see if the input matches a regular expression.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to limit the input. But you can validate the input afterward

Comment: @TreeNguyen: That's probably true, don't you have some easy snippet (probably jQuery) that could do that? Thanks

Comment: `each time user tries to submit the form` means you don't want the form to submit? You'll need AJAX in that case if you plan to use PHP.

Comment: @TreeNguyen There is a way to limit which characters can be entered by using the oninput attribute, but that only applies to one character at a time and doesn't help here.

Comment: The pattern atribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp might be good for disabling letters and allowing only numbers, but it won't check an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the far most I can get to without doing any dirty work.

https://jsfiddle.net/mankinchi/uupytLh2/

```
pattern="\d{4}"

if ((number < 1900) || (number > 2016))
```

This use the combination of having a pattern to check (4 digits only when submitting) and javascript (I used jQUery) to check for number range. The combination will allow you not messing around with a pattern in low level (limit the exact digit to be inputted).

However, if you still want to limit the user input, not checking afterward, you still can with oninput and manually limit out the next possible options.

Comment: Thanks, this, together with jQuery Validate script works very well, see below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery Validation plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/ that is great for this.

Just embed it and use:

```
$("#year_form").validate({
  lang: 'cs',
  rules: {
      year: {
      required: true,
      min: 1910,
      max: 2016
    }
  }
});
```